# Json encode showing result as string

Tags: php, json

I have been gone through previous stackoverflow suggestions and tried many ways but still json encode showing the result as a string not a plain output. Json has been been outputing to string normally and i want to display the result without string by removing string tag.

Code:

```
$vehiclResult = array(
'Fuel Type' => $VehicleFuel->Fuel_Type . "<br>",
     'Fuel Type Code' => $VehicleFuel->Fuel_Type_Code . "<br>",
     'Fuel Type Code' => $VehicleFuel->Fuel_Type_Code . "<br>",
     'ECE_Unit' => $VehicleFuel->ECE_Unit . "<br>",
     'ECE_In'=> $VehicleFuel->ECE_In . "<br>",
     'ECE_Out' => $VehicleFuel->ECE_Out . "<br>",
     'ECE_All' => $VehicleFuel->ECE_All . "<br>",
     'ECE_CO2' => $VehicleFuel->ECE_CO2 . "<br>"  
     ); 

     $result = array(       
        'vehicle' => $vehiclResult
     );   
     echo json_encode($result);
   die(); 
}
```

Output:

```
{"vehicle":{"Emission Class":"EU5
","Emission Badge":"4
","Car Tax":"146
","Tax Type":"D
","0":"Vehicle Fuel:
","Fuel Type":"Super
","Fuel Type Code":"1
","ECE_Unit":"l\/100km
","ECE_In":"9.2
","ECE_Out":"5.7
","ECE_All":"7
","ECE_CO2":"163
"}}
```

Comment: **json is string** what where you expecting? And whats with the break tags?

Comment: What is `plain output`? as per RTFM you know `json_encode()` returns string so all is fine.

Comment: the line breaks result from the `<br>` tags in the strings. If you look at the plain source of this output, you'll see, that it is perfectly fine JSON.

Comment: The only issue here is that your JSON is being parsed as HTML (you should have `header("Content-Type: application/json");`, but I've no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: i dont want result with ""

Comment: no i tried with header("Content-Type: application/json"); but still the same output

Comment: @user3844830 the quotes are required for string types, and property names with spaces - you cannot have valid json without them

Comment: I strongly recommend, that you read up on JSON, e.g., on [json.org](http://json.org).

Comment: i think my question was different. I know json returns string. I want to convert that string into plain output for display result

Comment: Your question isn't different. JSON is plain output. You simply can't explain what you want, but let's sum it up: you have an array that you converted to JSON **string**. That JSON is now usable by your browser for eval()-ing, so you can use the data in your javascript app. But no, you don't want a string, you want "plain output". Now what is plain output? Airplane? Jupiter? Higgs boson? Apple? We're not mind readers, and you invented some sort of your own terminology without letting anyone know about what you *mean* by  "plain output". Since string doesn't get any more plain than a string..

Comment: @user3844830 displayed how? As html, as plain text? Please edit your question with more details, including your expected output

Comment: So, you just want to remove the quotes in the json output? Try this `preg_replace("/\"/","",json_encode($result));`
Else, please be specific on what *plain output* you require.

Comment: I think you are right thts what i will try to remove string tag from json output. @N.B. you are going too far and talking too much and this is not the way to talk in stackoverflow. I know i have done mistake not explaining my question clearly but you dont have any sense to talk

Comment: @user3844830 - I'm not talking. I'm *typing*. And explaining to you what *you* wrote. Quite sad, isn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**In case you want these values in html page**

Use javascript http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/
to parse values from string.

```
var response = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(response);
```

Comment: So how does this relate to the question? Question's tags are `php` related, not JavaScript. Furthermore, this changes nothing in the data encoding, but just for decoding it later on.